# Centering text and image side by side

Tags: html, css, image

I am stuck with a **CSS problem** and I am calling out for your expertise to help me!

I am trying to align text and image. Text and image should be vertically centered, left aligned and fit right next to each other. Both elements should be **contained inside the wrapper div** that can have varying width.

Below is code that I have so far:

```
<style>
  .cell {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #999;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .text_element {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    float: left;
  }

  .tooltip_element {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }

</style>

<div class="cell">

  <div class="text_element"> This is some random, random text.</div>
  <div class="tooltip_element">
    <img src="http://www.sainsburysbank.co.uk/library/default/images/life-insurance/icon-tooltip.png"/>
  </div>

</div>
```

Above code produces next image when the wrapper content is **500px**:

[image]

In the above image elements fit correctly next to each other, but aren't vertically aligned.

For width **200px**, we get another problem however:

[image]

Here we get empty space between text and image, which shouldn't be there, as image should fit right next to the text. Furthermore image element is now outside the div.

**Note that:**

- wrapper content can have varying width
- solution should work in all browsers (no flex solutions)
- no JS, only CSS can be used

Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT:**

Text should be **left aligned**!

Comment: Do you want the image to always be inside the cell?

Comment: Yes, text and image should both be inside the cell.

Comment: @Riko Check my answer, I'm pretty sure it does exactly what you asked for without using script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here it is:

```css
.cell {
  width: 210px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #999;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.text_element {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip_element {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
  <div class="text_element">This is some random, random text. Moar random text. And moar, moar random text...
    <div class="tooltip_element">
      <img src="http://www.sainsburysbank.co.uk/library/default/images/life-insurance/icon-tooltip.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note I included the tooltip element inside the text element. So I could vertically align them. If they must be siblings, I'd need to wrap them both in a container for vertical centering without flex-box.

If you prefer jsFiddle, to play around with cell width, [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/xng0o2L9/1/).

Comment: I like your solution, however text should be left aligned. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: If it's left aligned the space between text and image is not controllable, it varies depending on the length (in letters) of the next word of the next line. What you ask for would be dificult even with javascript. That's not a reasonable request, imho.

Comment: I understand, but this is solution that is needed. I have already implemented several solutions.

Comment: Ok. Let's tackle this problem alone. Q: *Is it technically possible to calculate the distance between right margin and the closest letter to this margin for a text that has 2 lines and is left aligned*? A: **Nope.** I'm yet to find a solution using javascript, nevermind CSS only. I'm pretty sure CSS is not equipped for your request yet.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Truth be told, I'm first designer, than coder. I would justify and leave a few pixels between image and text anyway. And if I notice a very particular case while using it, where a very long word would make it look akward, I would rephrase that piece of content so it doesn't. This only looks bad when its on a very narrow cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **css table** https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/247/

**CSS**

```
.cell {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #999;
  word-break:break-all;
}

.text_element {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tooltip_element {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Comment: You missed the semicolon in `display: table`

Comment: While this is good, it doesn't align image right next to the text, when cell size is shrinked. As in next image: http://imgur.com/R3zk5wo

Comment: Nice touch with `break-all`. But I bet that's not allowed too. He's going to change the rules again.